# Add checkbox to Custom ExpandedListView android and create checked event

Tags: android, android-layout

I must create ExpandedListView and checkbox on each item. I want to when click checkbox of ParentItem(Item has child item) then all child item's check or uncheck(depend on check state of parent item), and if one child item check_change then state checked of parent is true if all child item is checked, else is false.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html
this   http://schimpf.es/listview-with-checkboxes-inside/
or this   http://androidcocktail.blogspot.ru/2012/04/adding-checkboxes-to-custom-listview-in.html

Or use  google.com

Answer (score 0):

I saw a library last night that might help you out

Check out here:
http://www.androidviews.net/2013/04/multichoiceadapter/

or their github:
https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/MultiChoiceAdapter